# UITableView appears partially clipped (blanked out) after receiving memory warning and "modal" view dismissed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, memory-management, user-interface

I have a product details screen that slides up into view when a user selects one of the products displayed in a table/grid view of products. I use CATransition to slide the view up, rather than use presentModalViewController.

The reason for this is because in the details screen, I allow the user to swipe left/right to navigate through the table of products and display the corresponding details. Again, the slide animation is done using CATransition. When I used a modal view to present the initial details screen, the swiped-in product screen would appear rotated and generally behave oddly. I assumed it had something to do with using CATransition within a modal view, so I decided to use CATransition to present the initial screen. Here is the code that does the slide animation:

```
+(void)slideFromView:(UIView*)currentView toView:(UIView*)nextView direction(CCUISlideDirection)direction{

  // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
  UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

  // remove the current view and replace with the next view to display
  [currentView removeFromSuperview];
  [theWindow addSubview:nextView];

  // set up an animation for the transition between the views
  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setDuration:0.5];
  [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
  switch (direction) {
    case CCUISlideLeft:
      [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
      break;
    case CCUISlideRight:
      [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
      break;
    case CCUISlideUp:
      [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
      break;
    case CCUISlideDown:
      [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];   
  [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
}
```

Now all the swiped-in view transitions work fine, until I receive a memory warning. After I receive the warning, and then dismiss/slide the details screen offscreen, part of the table/grid view of products appears clipped. Specifically, about 1/3 of the right side of the table appears white. See screenshot link below:

http://www.dropbox.com/gallery/19636498/1/work?h=4ecde7

Also, here is the delegate code to dismiss the view:

```
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
  MyWishesItemController* controller = (MyWishesItemController*)sender;
  [CCUIHelper slideFromView:controller.currentView toView:self.view direction:CCUISlideDown];
  if ([[_wishListResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0) {
    [self showWishList];
  }
  else {
    [self showEmptyList];
  }
}
```

Also, when I select a different tabbed view in the application and return to the table view, it appears fine. The odd thing to me is that it is only a part of the table that is blanked out. I've tried reloading the table when I receive the warning, but that didn't work. I've also run it through Instruments to identify and fix some leaks.

Other than clearing some caches in the didReceiveMemoryWarning method, and otherwise minimizing memory usage to avoid the warnings, what should I be doing to fix this problem.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have set in didReceiveMemoryWarning? Please post some code. Also post some screenshots if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your interest MishieMoo. I wanted to post a screenshot, but I don't have enough reputation points :( In my didReceiveMemoryWarning, I basically clear my cache of already viewed detail screens and then call supers warning method. This cache is used to store views of already viewed products, so they don't have to be recreated if the user swipes back to that product.

Comment: Hmm...can we see what code you have? And you can always link to images =) And the code you use to present/dismiss the view that is sliding.

Comment: MishieMoo, I really appreciate you taking the time to try and help me. :) I've updated my question with some code and a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Does your tableview use autosizing to resize after you slide in a view? Or does it normally cover? Have you tried reloading after dismissing the sliding view? Also, step through and see what the frame of your tableview is after the memory warning and dismissing the sliding view.

Comment: MishieMoo my dear, you rock! :) Looks like it was the auto-resizing. Probably would have taken me forever and a day to figure that one out on my own. How do I give points to you for pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the autosizing on your tableview. Make sure it is resizing correctly after the memory warning.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time! Sending good karma your way :)